# Can I simplify the population of this std::list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdlist

Can I simplify the populate of my `std::list` code:

```cpp
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitBrowserRegistryLookupList(RegistryPathList& rListRegPaths)
{
    S_REGISTRY_PATH  sRegPath;

    // Reset the list
    rListRegPaths.clear();

    // These will be "native" 32bit or native 64bit browsers (i.e. the Operating System bitness)
    sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe");
    sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Firefox");
    rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

    sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE");
    sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Internet Explorer");
    rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

    sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\chrome.exe");
    sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Google Chrome");
    rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

    sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\opera.exe");
    sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Opera Internet Browser");
    rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

    // These will be 32 bit browsers (on a 64 bit Operating System)
    if (IsOS(OS_WOW6432))
    {
        sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe");
        sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Firefox");
        rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

        sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE");
        sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Internet Explorer");
        rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);

        sRegPath.hRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        sRegPath.strKeyPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\chrome.exe");
        sRegPath.strBrowser = _T("Google Chrome");
        rListRegPaths.push_back(sRegPath);
    }
}
```

## Update

Definition of `RegPathlist`:

```
typedef struct tagRegistryPath
{
    HKEY hRootKey;
    CString strBrowser;
    CString strKeyPath;

} S_REGISTRY_PATH;
using RegistryPathList = list<S_REGISTRY_PATH>;
```

Comment: What is the `RegPathList` ? What is `S_REGPATH` ? There is no `std::list` in your code as you presented it now.

Comment: @KamilCuk Please see updated question.

Comment: Yes you can simplify that by providing configuration file with will list registry to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use initializer list constructor and `push_back`:

```
struct RegistryPath {
    HKEY hRootKey;
    TCHAR const* strBrowser;
    TCHAR const* strKeyPath;
};

int main() {
    std::list<RegistryPath> sRegPath = {
        {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"), _T("Firefox")},
        {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE"), _T("Internet Explorer")}
        // ...
    };
    if(IsOS(OS_WOW6432)) {
        sRegPath.push_back({HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"), _T("Firefox")});
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that I replaced `CString` with `TCHAR const*` to avoid memory allocations and copying the strings.

Comment: Thanks. Can `LPCTSTR` be used instead of `TCHAR const*` since I am in a `MFC` project?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sure, `LPCTSTR` can be used, it is a type alias for `TCHAR const*`.

Comment: The one fundamental issue here is that the structure is defined browser then path. So I have to swap the structure around so the fields match.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you would want to [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) your elements, which could speed up and "simplify" (subjective term) your code. Example:

```
rListRegPaths.emplace_back(
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
      _T("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"),
      _T("Firefox"));
```

Comment: When I try this I get a compile error: `Error C2661  'tagRegistryPath::tagRegistryPath': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments`

Comment: Also, the structure is defined with the `strBrowser` **first** and **then** the `strKeyPath`. So one or the other needs to have the values swapped around. Otherwise the wrong information is going into the wrong structure member variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can simplify that. The best way would be provide configuration file with contain this data.

If you don't want to use file just use initialization list (see version 5 of [std::list::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)):

```cpp
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitBrowserRegistryLookupList(RegistryPathList& rListRegPaths)
{
    rListRegPaths.insert(rListRegPaths.end(),
         {
             {
                 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                 _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"),
                 _T("Firefox")
             },
             {
                 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                 _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE"),
                 _T("Internet Explorer")
             },
             {
                 ....
             }
             ....
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the way you have formatted your code. :)

Comment: Thanks. The only mistake here is that the structure is defined with the `strBrowser` **first** and **then** the `strKeyPath`. So one or the other needs to have the values swapped around. Otherwise the wrong information is going into the wrong structure member variables.

Comment: I see not only I did that mistake :).

Answer (score 1):

You can make it shorter by constructing with arguments.

```cpp
typedef struct tagRegistryPath
{
    HKEY hRootKey;
    CString strBrowser;
    CString strKeyPath;

} S_REGISTRY_PATH;

rListRegPaths.push_back(S_REGISTRY_PATH {
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"),
    _T("Firefox")
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The only mistake here is that the structure is defined with the `strBrowser` **first** and **then** the `strKeyPath`. So one or the other needs to have the values swapped around. Otherwise the wrong information is going into the wrong structure member variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could create arrays with the different browsers, like this:

```cpp
S_REGISTRY_PATH native[] = { 
    {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"), _T("Firefox")},
    //...
}

S_REGISTRY_PATH wow64[] = {
   {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe"), _T("Firefox")},
    //...
}
```

This can even be a separate file, even automatically generated, which you would just include in the file implementing the method.
Then inside the method, all you would do is:

```cpp
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitBrowserRegistryLookupList(RegistryPathList& rListRegPaths)
{
    rListRegPaths.clear();

    for (auto && it : native) {
        rListRegPaths.push_back(*it);
    }

    if (IsOS(OS_WOW6432)) {
         for (auto && it : wow64) {
             rListRegPaths.push_back(*it);
         }
    }
}
```

This would separate what is basically just data from the code itself, which makes it much easier to read, change and generally manage.